# List posts that a user likes in CakePHP app

Tags: php, cakephp

I have two tables: Posts and Likes

And I'm trying to list the posts that the current logged in user likes. The method looks like the following:

```
$following = $this->Follower->listFollowing($this->Auth->user('id'));

$this->paginate = array('limit'=>20,'conditions'=>array('Post.id'=>array($following['Follower']['post_id']),'Post.status'=>array(1,2)),'order'=>array('Post.datetime'=>'desc'),
                        'contain'=>array('User','Answer'=>array('User'),'Tag'));

$this->set('posts',$this->paginate());
```

So basically what I'm trying to do is first query the following (likes) table for all matching rows to the user and then use this array of post ids in my find query to list posts that were in the query.

The listFollowing method in the Follower model looks like:

```
public function listFollowing($user_id)
    {
        return $this->find('all', array( 
            'conditions' => array('Follower.user_id'=>$user_id) 
        ));
    }
```

I'm currently getting an error like: `Undefined index: Follower [APP/Controller/PostsController.php, line 94]` So gonna presume that the way I'm trying to pass the list of post ids from the following in the find query is incorrect.

Can anyone help? Thanks

Edit: Doing a debug on $following gives:

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Follower' => array(
            'id' => '4',
            'user_id' => '6',
            'post_id' => '136'
        ),
        'User' => array(
            'password' => '*****',
            'id' => '6',
            'username' => 'driz',
            'email' => '######'
        ),
        'Post' => array(
            'id' => '136',
            'user_id' => '8',
            'datetime' => '2012-09-11 15:49:52',
            'modified' => '2012-09-16 15:31:38',
            'title' => 'Test Content',
            'slug' => 'Test_content',
            'content' => 'Test Content',
            'status' => '1'
        )
    ),
   (int) 1 => array(
        'Follower' => array(
            'id' => '5',
            'user_id' => '6',
            'post_id' => '133'
        ),
        'User' => array(
            'password' => '*****',
            'id' => '6',
            'username' => 'driz',
            'email' => '######'
        ),
        'Post' => array(
            'id' => '134',
            'user_id' => '8',
            'datetime' => '2012-09-11 15:49:52',
            'modified' => '2012-09-16 15:31:38',
            'title' => 'Test Content 2',
            'slug' => 'Test_content_2',
            'content' => 'Test Content 2',
            'status' => '1'
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of questions:

- Did you checked what query is being executed? If it's executed then probably the method is correct.
- is $following being populated? what happens if you debug it?
- if you are retreiving with 'all' then the result will look like this:

Array(

```
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ModelName] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 83
                    [field1] => value1
                    [field2] => value2
                    [field3] => value3
                )

            [AssociatedModelName] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [field1] => value1
                    [field2] => value2
                    [field3] => value3
                )

        )
)
```

So you'll never be able to find something at $following['Follower']. Check [Cake's documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html) for this

Based on you comments, if you need a list of id's try this inside your method:

```
public function listFollowing($user_id)
{
    return $this->find('list', array(
      'conditions' => array('Follower.user_id'=>$user_id) 
      'fields' => array('Follower.user_id'),
      'recursive' => 0);
}
```

The 'list' retrieve mode does exactlye that.

Comment: @Cameron then my guess is correct, there is no $following['Follower'] it should be $followging[0]['Follower']

Comment: What If I have lots of likes though? Would 0 still be correct? As I'm only getting the first like and not the full list as expected. If I replace 0 with 1 then it grabs the next one etc. How do I pull them all down?

Comment: Hey thanks. Still confused though. Where does that find list go? Would it go in the model to replace listFollowing? And how would I then use these results in my find query in the controller. If you could elaborate on your code example, that'd be awesome. Thanks.

Comment: @Cameron yes, check my answer I updated it with the complete method

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to guess the error with this limited information but I'm guessing that it's a PHP error related with your `$following` array.

Can you try putting `debug($following)` after your `listFollowing()` function call? So in the end, it should look like this:

```
$following = $this->Follower->listFollowing($this->Auth->user('id'));

debug($following);

$this->paginate = array('limit'=>20,'conditions'=>array('Post.id'=>array($following['Follower']['post_id']),'Post.status'=>array(1,2)),'order'=>array('Post.datetime'=>'desc'),
                        'contain'=>array('User','Answer'=>array('User'),'Tag'));

$this->set('posts',$this->paginate());
```

You will see what is returned from `listFollowing()` that is causing an index error. You can further debug it with that information. I can no longer help as there is no database schema, full code, the variables/situation that causes this problem, etc :)

Comment: You get an array of Followers. So, if you want to get a list of posts, you will need to iterate over $following list, getting all the id's and querying posts. You may want to use `foreach`

Comment: @ErenT. don't you think is better to change the retrieve mode? the 'list' mode does that so you don't have to iterate through the result

Comment: @LuisClemente right, but isn't it still an array that needs to be traversed to get full posts? In list mode, the structure of the array is changed, there is still need to traverse.